# Append value into multi-valued field if table match

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables. A master table, and a source table. Inside the master table I have a multi-value field named 'completed' with [Applied, Pledged, Transcripts]. What I want to happen is for 'Pledged' to be appended into the multi-value field if the records match in master and source. So far this is my code:

```
INSERT INTO Contacts ( Completed.[Value] )
VALUES ('Pledged')
FROM Source
WHERE Contacts.Email = Source.Email;
```

When I run the query on Access it tells me "Missing semicolon(;) at end of SQL statement. I'm not sure what I should tweak. All help is appreciated!

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql` tag for MS-Access questions.

Answer (score 2):

Consider INNER JOIN instead of WHERE with a SELECT clause instead of VALUES.

```
INSERT INTO Contacts (Completed.[Value])
SELECT 'Pledged' AS Data
FROM Source INNER JOIN Contacts ON Source.Email = Contacts.Email;
```

Comment: He wants to append to a column in an existing row, not create a new row.

Comment: Not creating a new record, adding a value in multi-value field of existing record. Tested. Works.

Comment: I guess I should keep my nose out of Access questions, I'm not familiar with that feature of them.

Comment: Must understand that multi-value field is really representing a hidden table, so yes, this is actually creating a new record in that hidden table.